# extracting total days of a month and then use it to get average sales per day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, report

Hi i've been working on this project and need to get this.

```
SELECT  sf.ORDER_QNT, dd.ACTUAL_DATE, dd.MONTH_NUMBER 
FROM    sales_fact sf,
        date_dim dd
WHERE   dd.date_id = sf.date_id
AND dd.MONTH_NUMBER = 1;
```

the result is the following:

```
 ORDER_QNT ACTUAL_DATE MONTH_NUMBER
---------- ----------- ------------
      1100    05/01/13            1 
       100    05/01/13            1 
       140    06/01/13            1 
       110    07/01/13            1 
       200    08/01/13            1 
       500    08/01/13            1 
       230    08/01/13            1 
       500    08/01/13            1 
       200    08/01/13            1 
        53    15/01/13            1 
        53    22/01/13            1
```

Now, I want to get the average for that month (average per day).

```
SELECT  sum(sf.ORDER_QNT)/31 as AVGPERDAY
FROM    sales_fact sf,
        date_dim dd
WHERE   dd.date_id = sf.date_id
AND     dd.MONTH_NUMBER = 1;
```

The question is, instead of putting 31, how can I get the total day of the month? and how can I apply that to the SELECT query. I'm pretty good with logic(c++), but this database is pretty new to me. I'm using Oracle 11g by the way. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is, instead of putting 31, how can I get the total day of the month?

Pick any one solution :

1.
You can add a month to a date and substract both the dates :

`ADD_MONTHS(date_col, 1) - date_col`

Example :

```
SQL> WITH dates AS(
  2  SELECT to_date('05/01/13','mm/dd/rr') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT to_date('06/01/13','mm/dd/rr') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT to_date('02/01/13','mm/dd/rr') dt FROM dual)
  5  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(dt, 1) - dt num_of_days_per_month
  6  from dates
  7  /

NUM_OF_DAYS_PER_MONTH
---------------------
                   31
                   30
                   28
```

Or,

2. You can extract the last day of the month :

`EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY (date_col))`

Example :

```
SQL> WITH dates AS(
  2  SELECT to_date('05/01/13','mm/dd/rr') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT to_date('06/01/13','mm/dd/rr') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT to_date('02/01/13','mm/dd/rr') dt FROM dual)
  5  SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(dt)) num_of_days_per_month
  6  from dates
  7  /

NUM_OF_DAYS_PER_MONTH
---------------------
                   31
                   30
                   28
```